# Select all child elements except the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following:

```
<ul>
 <li>First item</li>
 <li>Second item</li>
 <li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

How would I select all the child elements after the first one using jQuery?  So I can achieve something like:

```
<ul>
 <li>First item</li>
 <li class="something">Second item</li>
 <li class="something">Third item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You should be able to use the "not" and "first child" selectors.

```
$("li:not(:first-child)").addClass("something");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/firstChild

Comment: I tried this:

$('.certificateList input:checkbox :not(:first-child)')

but it didn't work....

Comment: Will this be slower than the Slice method listed below?

Answer (score 39):

Based on my totally unscientific analysis of the four methods here, it looks like there's not a lot of speed difference among them. I ran each on a page containing a series of unordered lists of varying length and timed them using the Firebug profiler.

```
$("li").slice(1).addClass("something");
```

Average Time: 5.322ms

```
$("li:gt(0)").addClass("something");
```

Average Time: 5.590ms

```
$("li:not(:first-child)").addClass("something");
```

Average Time: 6.084ms

```
$("ul li+li").addClass("something");
```

Average Time: 7.831ms

Comment: I came across this question cause I needed to get all children but the first.  I was doing this on all the h3's that were in a div.  I ran three of the queries like you had above on my page and came away with :not(:first-child) as being the fastest by 2-3 times.  I think the way your page is structured may also play in to profile speeds.  Either way though this answer taught me how to use the Firebug profiler and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 13):

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice

```
$("li").slice(1).addClass("something");
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I feel what I selected as the answer is the more explicit usage.  Anyone new to the project will have quicker grasp on what is being done in the selector.

Answer (score 9):

A more elegant query (select all li elements that are preceded by a li element):

`$('ul li+li')`

Comment: $("li+li") will likely work faster then $("li:not(:first-child)")

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
$('ul :not(:first-child)').addClass('something');
```

Answer (score 3):

i'd use

```
$("li:gt(0)").addClass("something");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have working so far

```
$('.certificateList input:checkbox:gt(0)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery .not() method

```
$('li').not(':first').addClass('something');
```

OR

```
var firstElement = $('li').first();
$('li').not(firstElement).addClass('something');
```

Comment: This one works if the children are not all the same element type. 
You make  your selector for the parent element, then use the .children() selector and then the .not(':first') selector.