# How to avoid looping for accessing each element except the first child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row m-0 be_product_grid_image">
      <divclass="col_classes">
      <img src="img1.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="row m-0 be_product_grid_image">
      <divclass="col_classes">
      <img src="img2.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="row m-0 be_product_grid_image">
      <divclass="col_classes">
      <img src="img3.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="row m-0 be_product_grid_image">
      <divclass="col_classes">
      <img src="img4.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="row m-0 be_product_grid_image">
      <divclass="col_classes">
      <img src="img5.png" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to show all images except the first image on clicking the '**show all**' *button*
similarly hide all images except first image on clicking '**show less**' *button*

Comment: Ask question when you stuck in code which will try to give answers to guide you or trying new possibilities in life of coding. So first do some code and then come back here if you stuck any where. 
How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select all child elements except the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178407/select-all-child-elements-except-the-first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var images = $('.be_product_grid_image:not(:first)');

$(document).on('click', 'your_show_all_button', function() {
     images.show()
})

$(document).on('click', 'your_show_less_button', function() {
     images.hide()
})
```

Try applying this method by replacing *your_show_all_button* and *your_show_less_button* with your buttons' class or id

Answer (score 0):

Add two buttons for show and hide:

```
<button id="showAllBtn" onclick="showAllImages()">Show All</button>
<button id="showLessBtn" onclick="showLessImages()">Show Less</button>
```

Add js script for the functionalities:

```
function showAllImages() {
   var images = document.querySelectorAll('.be_product_grid_image');

   for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].style.display = 'block';
   }
   document.getElementById('showAllBtn').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('showLessBtn').style.display = 'inline-block';
}

function showLessImages() {
   var images = document.querySelectorAll('.be_product_grid_image');

   for (var i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
   
   document.getElementById('showAllBtn').style.display = 'inline-block';
   document.getElementById('showLessBtn').style.display = 'none';
}
```